# Nautilus opens twice in Classic Gnome

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Environment: Ubuntu 11.10 / 12.04 with Classic Gnome
Situation: Choose Nautilus of specific location
Problem: It looks like Nautilus is opening 2 windows. After a while the second one dies.

Question: Why and how to prevent that problem?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Gnome Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663770) and as such is now closed.

Comment: Why is this question closed? The bug report exists, but it doesn't contain a solution (or workaround) which answer(s) to this question give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to stop this behavior pending a gnome bug fix you may try this, tested on 12.04

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`

Look for this line `StartupNotify=true`, change it to `StartupNotify=false`

Then restart nautilus or simply do a log out/in

There are 2 other nautilus .desktop's, home-folder.desktop & nautilus-folder-handler.desktop, I believe you can leave them as is

Comment: The use of gksu;gksudo is not needed when using  a sudo gedit, it actually also opens the pita "untitled Document". There is no documentation that using sudo gedit is a problem. If concerned then sudo -H gedit is a better option than gksu

Comment: My comment about the use of sudo gedit is only for 12.04 & earlier. For 14.04 & later it is not advised anymore, use `gksudo gedit` or `sudo -H gedit`

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you start an app in GNOME Fallback mode, the window list button first displays 'Opening App' which then changes to 'App' after the application has started. This is to indicate startup. Not so with Nautilus. When it starts the 'Opening $LOCATION' message is displayed on another window list button.

see: http://imagebin.org/198417

Btw. I have reported an upstream bug which has been ignored since 201111:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663770